# There are two different effects of mouse style in different system , Why?

Tags: qt, qt4

I want to change the mouse style .

```
QCursor a ;
QPixmap pixmap(“ .....”) ;
a = QCursor(pixmap,-1,-1);
setCursor(a) ;
```

That's my resource image .Oh! new users aren't allowed to post images! 55555....
Let me show my own description!  This image is a  white ring with edge of blue .

It is normal in Fedora , But it is abnormal in Ubuntu and my customize linux with arm 9 .
What I want to emphasize is the fact that the phenomenon is  very strange.It can only display 2 colors : white or black.

I want to know How I can display the normal style in all systems. What factors affect it ?

Thanks.

Comment: [QCursor docs](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qcursor.html) say: *On X11, Qt supports the Xcursor library, which allows for full color icon themes.* Maybe you need to install libxcursor/xcursor-dev or similar on your Ubuntu and arm 9 systems before you can use full colour cursors.

Comment: I get it . 
The reason is that opacity of the widget has changed .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get it . 
The reason is that opacity of the widget has changed .